# No product was added to database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I fixed Warning error but no product was added to my database.
I don't know what my fault is? Hope that anyone can help me

Here is my code in add.php:

```
if ($_POST) {
// Image 1
$image_name_1 = $_FILES ['image_1'] ['name'];
$image_type_1 = $_FILES ['image_1'] ['type'];
$image_size_1 = $_FILES ['image_1'] ['size'];
$image_tmp_name_1 = $_FILES ['image_1'] ['tmp_name'];

if ($image_name_1 == '' || $image_name_1 == null) {
    echo "<script> alert('Please select an image')</script>";
} else
    move_uploaded_file ( $image_tmp_name_1, '../../userfiles/' . $image_name_1 );

    // Image 2
$image_name_2 = $_FILES ['image_2'] ['name'];
$image_type_2 = $_FILES ['image_2'] ['type'];
$image_size_2 = $_FILES ['image_2'] ['size'];
$image_tmp_name_2 = $_FILES ['image_2'] ['tmp_name'];

if ($image_name_2 == '' || $image_name_2 == null) {
    echo "<script> alert('Please select an image')</script>";
} else
    move_uploaded_file ( $image_tmp_name_2, '../../userfiles/' . $image_name_2 );

    // Image 3
$image_name_3 = $_FILES ['image_3'] ['name'];
$image_type_3 = $_FILES ['image_3'] ['type'];
$image_size_3 = $_FILES ['image_3'] ['size'];
$image_tmp_name_3 = $_FILES ['image_3'] ['tmp_name'];

if ($image_name_3 == '' || $image_name_3 == null) {
    echo "<script> alert('Please select an image')</script>";
} else
    move_uploaded_file ( $image_tmp_name_3, '../../userfiles/' . $image_name_3 );

$data = array (
        'category_id' => $_POST ['category_id'],
        'name' => $_POST ['name'],
        'price' => $_POST ['price'],
        'detail' => $_POST ['detail'],
        'img_1' => $image_name_1,
        'img_2' => $image_name_2,
        'img_3' => $image_name_3,
        'status' => isset ( $_POST ['status'] ) ? 1 : 0,
        'created' => date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
        'modified' => date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) 
);


if (add_product ( $data )) {
    $_SESSION ['success'] = true;
    // rdr to list.php
    header ( 'location:list.php' );
}
 }
```

Here is **add-form**

```
<form name="add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th><select name="category_id">
                <?php while($category_active = mysql_fetch_assoc($category_active_list)): ?>
                <option
                        value="<?php echo $category_active['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category_active['name']; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </select></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Detail</th>
            <th><textarea name="detail"></textarea></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th><input type="file" name="image_1" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Image 2</th>
            <th><input type="file" name="image_2" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Image 3</th>
            <th><input type="file" name="image_3" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><input type="submit" value="Add" name="btnAdd" /></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and **function add**

```
function add_product($data) {
// SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_product(category_id, name, price,detail, img_1, img_2, img_3, status, created, modified) VALUES({$data['category_id']}, '{$data['name']}', {$data['price']}, '{$data['detail']}', '{$data['image_1']}', '{$data['image_2']}', '{$data['image_3']}', {$data['status']}, '{$data['created']}', '{$data['modified']}')";
return mysql_query ( $sql );
}
```

How to fix it?.Tks all

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: are you sure the folder userfiles exists?

Comment: #tadman tks for your tips.I'll learn it

Comment: #talhiner yes,Im sure .I created that folder in my project

Comment: Read & Write Permissions not given to `userfiles` folder.

Comment: `userfiles` folder is present in `Product` folder or `admin` folder ?

Comment: Here is my project structure
http://i.imgur.com/68OQSxi.png

Answer (score 2):

Since, Your **add.php** is present in `admin->product` folder. So, you need to go two directory back to save images in `userfiles` folder.

No changes in code, except

```
move_uploaded_file ( $image_tmp_name_1, '../../userfiles/' . $image_name_1 );
```

Append `../../` in `userfiles/`

Comment: Have you changed in all 3 lines where `move_uploaded` code is written @optimus.prime30 ?

Comment: Append only `../` in all 3 lines. Not `../../` @optimus.prime30. Yes, why not. We are here to help each other. Don't worry.

Comment: If I append `../` code will get error as above,so I append `../../` ,there's no warning

Comment: `../` will come to `admin` folder. And, one more `../` will come to `shop` folder. There Itself `userfiles` folder are present. Append `../../`, It will work @optimus.prime30

Comment: But no product was added to my database

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of that folder. whether Read and write permissions are granted to it or not.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?.This is my first time in working with upload image.Thanks

Comment: You working on localhost ? And, What's your OS ? Ubuntu or Windows ? @optimus.prime30

Comment: I set full permissions on folder . Have any steps ? If no,code still not work :(

Comment: This much only I can try from here. Some other problem is there which I don't know may be @optimus.prime30.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support :)